# Rails 3 has_one with join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-one

I have the following:

```
has_many :sports, :through => :user_sports
has_one :primary_sport, class_name: "UserSport", conditions: ["user_sports.primary = ?", true]
has_many :user_sports
```

When I run this in console:

```
athlete = Athlete.all.last
athlete.primary_sport
```

The record that is returned is the record from the join table instead of the record joining the sports table. Any way to return the actual sport from the join?

Answer (score 0):

You might probably do something like this:

```
class UserSport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :athletes
  has_many :sports
end


athlete = Athlete.all.last
athlete.primary_sport.sport
```

Didn't try it by myself, just check and see :)

Comment: that works, I was just trying to do this without having to drill down the object association